# How to document function-based views parameters?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, swagger, django-swagger

I'm developing a REST API with Django 1.11 and Django REST Framework 3.7. I installed [Django REST Swagger](https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-swagger) 2.1 to generate the documentation.

I'm using a function-based view like this:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, permission_classes

@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes((permissions.AllowAny,))
def jwt_auth(request, provider, format=None):
    """
    View description here
    """
    pass
```

[image: Generated documentation by Swagger]

As you can see, my view is recognized by Swagger and it has the correct description: "*View description here*".

However:

- You can see the "*Description*" column is empty for the `provider` URL parameter.
- The POST parameters are not documented (obviously, because there is no way for Swagger to know them)

**How can I write documentation for the URL and POST parameters of a function-based view, as well as the responses?**

I tried [YAML Docstrings](http://django-rest-swagger.readthedocs.io/en/stable-0.3.x/yaml.html) but it seems it's for the old version (0.3.x) and it doesn't work with version 2.x.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Schema of DjangoRestFrameWork.
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/schemas/

In your case, you can try the following.

---

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, permission_classes, schema
from rest_framework import permissions

@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes((permissions.AllowAny,))
@schema(custom_schema)
def jwt_auth(request, provider, format=None):
    """
    View description here
    """
    pass
```

---

custom schema defintion

```
import coreapi, coreschema
from rest_framework.schemas import AutoSchema, ManualSchema

custom_schema = AutoSchema(manual_fields=[
    coreapi.Field("username", required=True, location="form", type="string", description="username here"),
    coreapi.Field("password", required=True, location="form", type="string", description="password field")
])
```

Should do the trick.
For more detailed info, visit the link I provided at the top. Basic POST and GET parameters should work in this way.

Answer (score 1):

Following this [github issue](https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-swagger/issues/549), it seems it's not possible for the method-based views as you stated.

But I think [this link](https://github.com/m-haziq/django-rest-swagger-docs#advance-usage) can help you.

Answer (score 0):

use below code

```
@swagger_auto_schema(method='post', auto_schema=None)
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes((permissions.AllowAny,))
def jwt_auth(request, provider, format=None):
    """
    View description here
    """
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

I have explained the answer to this question. Please follow this StackOverflow link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67688437/8484740